# How to make double $lookup aggregation with nested data on MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have 3 models:

1. Study
2. WordSet
3. Category

**Study model has reference into WordSet, then WordSet has reference into Category.**

I understand that for display data normally, I use populate.
But in this situation, I need a query with many `$lookup`.

How I can 'populate' Category from WordSet and display only that category which was repeated the most?

I would achieve a response like this:

```
"stats": [
    {
        "_id": null,
        "numberOfStudies": 4,
        "averageStudyTime": 82.5,
        "allStudyTime": 330,
        "longestStudy": 120,
        "allLearnedWords": 8
        "hardestCategory": "Work" // only this field is missing
    }
]
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
   const stats = await Study.aggregate([
  {
    // join User table 
    $lookup: {
      from: 'User',
      let: { userId: '$user' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } },
        },
      ],
      as: 'currentUser',
    },
  },
  {
   // join WordSet table
    $lookup: {
      from: 'WordSet',
      let: { wordSetId: '$learnedWordSet' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$wordSetId'] } },
        },
        {
         // from this moment i'm not sure how to make it work
          $lookup: {
            from: 'Category',
            let: { categoryId: '$category' },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$categoryId'] } },
              },
            ],
            as: 'category',
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'wordSet',
    },
  },
  { // add wordset with category? this is not working
    $addFields: {
      wordSet: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$wordSet', 0],
      },
    },
  },
  { // search by logged user
    $match: { user: new ObjectID(currentUserId) },
  },
  { 
    $group: {
      // display statistics about user's studying
      _id: null,
      numberOfStudies: { $sum: 1 },
      averageStudyTime: { $avg: '$studyTime' },
      allStudyTime: { $sum: '$studyTime' },
      longestStudy: { $max: '$studyTime' },
      allLearnedWords: { $sum: { $size: '$learnedWords' } },
      // category: check which category is repeated the most and display it
    },
  },
]);
```

Study

```
     const studySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  studyTime: {
    type: Number,
  },
  learnedWords: [String],
  notLearnedWords: [String],
  learnedWordSet: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'WordSet',
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});
```

WordSet

```
const wordSetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      category: {
        type: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

Category

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand correctly, you can try the query and i have improved the usage of stages,

- `$match` always try to use stage in the first stage

> - `$lookup` with User collection, there is no need to pipeline version, you can use localField and foreignField properties
>
> > I don't think is there any use of user document, and lookup stage because you want only statistics as per last `$group` stage. so you can skip this lookup stage

- inside WordSet lookup,

  - `$match` your condition
  - `$project` to show required fields
  - `$unwind` deconstruct the `category` array
  - `$group` by `category` and get the total count
  - `$sort` by `count` in descending order
  - `$limit` to get only the first and single element that is most used
  - `$llokup` with `Category` collection
  - `$project` to show required fields, get first category name
- `$group` stage, `hardestCategory` get `$first` category name

```
const stats = await Study.aggregate([
  { $match: { user: new ObjectID(currentUserId) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "User",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "currentUser"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "WordSet",
      let: { wordSetId: "$learnedWordSet" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$wordSetId"] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            category: 1
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$category" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$category",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Category",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            category: { $arrayElemAt: ["$category.name", 0] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "wordSet"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      numberOfStudies: { $sum: 1 },
      averageStudyTime: { $avg: "$studyTime" },
      allStudyTime: { $sum: "$studyTime" },
      longestStudy: { $max: "$studyTime" },
      allLearnedWords: {
        $sum: { $size: "$learnedWords" }
      },
      hardestCategory: {
        $first: {
          $first: "$wordSet.category"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m6agRZOOady)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the explanation. There is one missing piece because: hardestCategory return null on my response. Do you know why?

Comment: just make sure the category collection name in database.

Comment: on my db my collections are named diffrently than in node/mongoose. On db i have: users, studies, categories, wordsets. But while quering, aggregating i use for e.g 'User' instead of 'users'.

Comment: so yes you need to use exact as per your collection, users, categories .... in lookup `from` property

Comment: wow! you were right. I thought i must use model names with first capital letters. Thank you for help. i'm very grateful.

Comment: could you help me once more? I forgot about one thing.. I would need to display hardestCategory by this condition: 'Display hardest category based on in which study size of notLearnedWords was the highest' @turivishal

Comment: so you don't need the most repeated category condition?

Comment: No i don't need that. Instead, I need to display hardest category based on in which study size of not Learned Words was the highest @turivishal

Comment: not getting your exact requirement, notLearnedWords is a field of study collection, and what type of condition you need?

Comment: studyModel has field 'notLearnedWords' which is array of strings. Based on that i need to display hardestCategory. My logic behinde that is: search all studies -> select only that one with the highest notLearnedWords (i believe it's $size operator) and as final result display category.name from selected study as hardestCategory. Do you understand now? @turivishal

Comment: look ath the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yaQ3n_1XE2Q), hope this help, don't have much time.